# Let $A$ and $B$ be any two nonempty sets. Prove that there exists $f: A \to B$ that has at least one of these properties:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(i) f is one-to-one

(ii) f is onto B

So I was thinking of doing this proof as a case by case, but I'm not sure if that's how I would go about this one. The 3 cases I had in mind were: Both cardinalities are equal, cardinality of A is greater than the cardinality of B and the reverse. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the sets finite? If not, can we assume the axiom of choice?

Comment: The question does not specify if they are finite, but we can assume the axoim of choice.

Comment: I think if $|A| < |B|$, then we can show (without AOC) that an injection $f$ exists.  The reverse is where the AOC comes in, I believe.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think you need AC to even determine if |A| < |B| (if both are infinite) since otherwise it's possible |A| or |B| is not an $\aleph$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Your basic idea is sound, but you can reduce it to two cases. If $|A|\le|B|$, then by definition there is an injection from $A$ to $B$. If $|A|>|B|$, then $|B|<|A|$, so there is an injection $g:B\to A$; now use $g$ to define a surjection $f:A\to B$.

As **Dan Simon** said in the comments, you need the axiom of choice in order to say that either $|A|\le|B|$ or $|A|>|B|$; there are models of set theory without $\mathsf{AC}$ in which there are sets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|\not\le|B|$ and $|B|\not\le|A|$, and in fact in which the result that you’re trying to prove is false.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: @Robin: You're very welcome!